# Каким способом расширить монитор?

Tags: windows

У меня два ноутбука (win 8 и win 10). Хочу "расширить" (extend) или соединить, не знаю как правильно сказать мониторы, не дублировать экран, а чтобы их было 2, чтобы мышкой можно с одного на другой переходить. И без проводов! По интернету, WIFI или по какой-нибудь домашней сети.

Быстрый поиск в интернете не дал ответ, там все про телевизоры, да HDMI.

Comment: расширить между двумя разными осями? И как вы себе представляете перетаскивание из вин8 в вин10)))

Comment: Виртуальную ось или удаленный терминал сервер поднимите, да цепляйтесь к нему с обоих компов хотя бы RAT-средствами. И будет Вам счастье.